# How do you set the magnitude and the phase of the DFT of an image to a specific value?

Tags: numpy, computer-vision, dft, phase, magnitude

I have the DFT of a picture and I need to set its magnitude and its phase to zero, separately.

Also if the magnitude of an image is 0 it will appear entirely as black, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mistakenly assuming that there is such a thing as *the* phase and *the* magnitude. Each spatial frequency has a phase and magnitude, that's why you get one complex number per frequency.

And an image is black when *all* magnitudes are zero.

Comment: So what you're saying is that an image is the sum of many spatial frequencies, right? And if I wanted to set the phase or the magnitude of all those frequencies to zero, how would I do that?

Comment: Correct. I don't know the exact representation you're using, but something like `std::fill(yourBegin, yourEnd, std::complex<double>{})` comes to mind.